# delphi to C++ builder conversion

Tags: delphi, c++builder, boolean-operations, binary-operators

I have source code in Delphi I follow this http://hscripts.com/tutorials/cpp/bitwise-operators.php for bitwise operators to convert it in C++ Builder, but the result is different

Source code in Delphi

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject)
var
    tmp, dynamicINT : integer;
begin
    dynamicINT := 42080;
    tmp := ((dynamicINT shl 1) or (dynamicINT shr 31) and $7FFFFFFF);

    Edit1.Text := IntToHex(tmp, 4);
end;
```

Delphi result : `148C0` correct!

Source code in C++ Builder

```cpp
void __fasctall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    int dynamicINT = 42080;

    tmp = ((dynamicINT << 1) || (dynamicINT >> 31) && 0x7FFFFFFF);
    Edit1->Text = IntToHex(tmp, 4);
}
```

C++ Builder result : `0001` ???

What is wrong with conversion ?

I'm using C++ Builder 6 and Delphi 7

Comment: Why are you porting? C++-Builder has "a Delphi on board"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`||` and `&&` are logical operators in C++, not bitwise operators. They only return true/false. The corresponding binary operators are `|` and `&`.

Try:

```
tmp = ((dynamicINT << 1) | (dynamicINT >> 31) & 0x7FFFFFFF);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using logical operators. You need to use bitwise operators, `&` and `|`. What's more the C++ code needlessly initializes and then overwrites the `tmp` variable. Your code should be:

```
int dynamicINT = 42080;
int tmp = ((dynamicINT << 1) | (dynamicINT >> 31) & 0x7FFFFFFF);
```

One thing to be careful about in the translation is what is meant by the shift operators when applied to signed types. I believe that there will be no problem with the code in the question since `dynamicINT` has a fixed value. But perhaps in the real code it can vary. In which case you may encounter implementation defined or undefined behaviour.

I suspect that you should be using untyped variables here. I'd have these variables as `Cardinal` in the Delphi code and `unsigned int` in the C++ code.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Mat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23753355/2932052), it might help you for porting to know that in C/C++, as opposed to Delphi/Pascal, **any `bool` value is interchangeable** with all integral and numeric types. The following nonsense example will not cause any warning by the compiler:

```
bool a = 6 * 7.89;
int b = true & 128;
float f = a + !b; // which is 2
```

...and last but not least: **You may use Delphi unit files unchanged in C++-Builder projects.** just try to add one of them to your project (this way you can do the migration - if still needed - step by step).